# Creating an error message for an invalid input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling, user-input

I have been trying to create a program that creates a list from user input. The program is meant to give an error message to the user input when the length of the list is more or less than nine (9)

For example:
"Please enter nine (9) numbers from 0 - 100: "

input
4 5 6 7 8 9
output
Sorry! Numbers should be up to nine.

or
input
5 67 8 2 90 65 3 45 2 7 1 0
"Sorry! Numbers should not be more than nine."

my code:

```
number = []
while True:
    num =  input("Please type numbers: ")
    num = list(map(int, num.split()))
    number.append(num)
    if len(number) > 9:
        print ("Numbers should not be more than 9!")
    
    else:
        break

print (number)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
number = []
num = input("Please type numbers: ")
num = list(map(int, num.split()))
number.append(num)
while True:

    if (len(number)) == 7:
        print ("List is complete")
    elif (len(number)) < 7:
        print ("List is not complete")
    else:
        print ("List is more than 7")
    break
```

this code works fine when I'm not asking for user input.
However it brings back the output
"List is not complete" whenever I run it without regard for the length of the string.

Comment: "The program is meant to give an error message to the user input when the length of the list is more or less than nine (9)" Well, in your own words, where in the code is the attempt to test whether the length is less than nine?

Comment: "I don't know what I am doing wrong." Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Make sure you understand that this is not a debugging service. After you have made your best attempt to [find the problem yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), make sure to **ask a specific question** in your post - it should start with a question word like "how" or "why", end with a question mark (`?`), and make it clear to us exactly what help you need in order to solve the problem.

Comment: When describing the problem, make sure it is clear: How do you try to test the code? What happens when you do that? What is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Karl. The code just gives me the list of the numbers inputted by the user, somehow it skips the if condition. My major question is how do i put in a code that will give me an error message if the length of the list is more?

Comment: I believe the problem is coming from this string of code | num = list(map(int, num.split())) | that tries to split the user input and convert it to integer at the same time.

Comment: "However it brings back the output "List is not complete" whenever I run it without regard for the length of the string." Did you try to check the value that you get for `num` when you run the code? Also: please keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum or a debugging service. Try not to go back and forth posting multiple versions of the code, because this confuses anyone who comes across the question later. The goal is to produce something that can help people in the future when they find the question with a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a list within a list, like this

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]
```

to solve this problem, you just have to replace `number.append(num)` by `number = num` or simply use directly the variable num like this

```py
num = input("Please type numbers: ")
num = list(map(int, num.split()))


while True:

    if (len(num)) == 7:
        print ("List is complete")
    elif (len(num)) < 7:
        print ("List is not complete")
    else:
        print ("List is more than 7")
    break
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I couldn't understand what I was doing wrong. I am very grateful.